# If a solution exists, how can I construct another solution with coprime integers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pell-type-equations

Suppose , $n$ is an odd positive integer and positive integers $a,b$ not being coprime satisfy the equation $$a^2-2b^2=n$$

> Can I always find a solution of $$c^2-2d^2=n$$ with coprime integers $c,d$ ?

I know that I can construct infinite many solutions from one solution of this pell-like equation, but the problem is that the usual procedure gives integers not being coprime , if I start with a solution with integers not being coprime. What can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider $n=9$.

There are non-coprime solutions
gotten by taking solutions to
$x^2-2y^2=1$
and multiplying them by $3$.

Suppose
$c^2-2d^2 = 9$.
Mod 3,
$d^2 = 0$ or $1$.
Therefore
$2d^2 = 0$
or $2$,
so $c^2 = 0$ or $2$.
This can only hold
if $c^2 = 0$,
so $c = 0$
mod 3.
Therefore
$d = 0$ mod 3
so $c$ and $d$
are not relatively prime.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this counterexample (+1). If $n$ has only prime factors of the form $8k\pm 1$, is there still a counterexample ?

Answer (score -1):

Knowing the first solution $(x_0 ; y_0)$ for the equation. $$x^2-qy^2=n$$

It is necessary to use any solution of the Pell equation.  $$p^2-qs^2=1$$

Then knowing what some solution $(x_0 ; y_0)$ we can find the following for equation $x^2-qy^2=n$

$$x=px_0+qsy_0$$

$$y=sx_0+py_0$$

Comment: I search a solution with coprime integers.

Comment: @Peter These are solutions in integers. The Pell equation in this form gives solutions in integers. Solutions can only be written this way. Use the previous one to get the next one. There is no other parameterization.

Comment: This method does not necessarily produce all possible solutions.

Comment: @Peter This is the only method and the only approach. And he gives all solutions. If you don't like him, it won't make him bad.

Comment: We need the complete set of fundamental solutions to get all solutions. We cannot calculate all solutions in general just with one solution and the pell-equation with $1$

Comment: @Peter It is necessary to know all the first fundamental decisions. $x^2-qy^2=n$ All others are according to this formula.